# Bitlbee and ZNC: is it possible to keep query history on all clients

Tags: irc, instant-messaging

I have installed bitlbee to emulate all my contacts from various instant messaging services as IRC contacts. In order to keep history, and allow them to message me when I'm not connected to IRC, I also installed ZNC (an IRC bouncer).

However, while ZNC seems to work well for IRC *channels* (I properly get the previous messages when I connect with any IRC client), it doesn't really work for queries (direct chat with someone, i.e. not in a channel). But with my setup, I actually only have queries (excepted bitlbee control channel which I don't really care about).

I've tried disabling ZNC `Auto Clear Query Buffer` option, but it doesn't work well either, because IRC clients think they receive *new* messages (and bip and vibrate) each time I connect to ZNC. Also, they will reopen all query windows even for old conversations. And finally, some clients remember history for previously open query windows, so they append the same discussion again.

Is it possible to make bitlbee create a channel for each of my contacts so that ZNC would provide proper history? Or any other idea to get it to work?

I'm also open to alternative solutions to achieve the same goal (unifying multiple instant messaging services with a unique always-connected server, to which I can ponctually connect with a unique client and have history of all conversations ; I would ideally need the client(s) to be available on Windows, Linux and Android).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make bitlbee create a channel for each of my
>   contacts so that ZNC would provide proper history? Or any other idea
>   to get it to work?

That would work. You could put the contacts you care about in individual groups. Then do `channel <id> set fill_by group`. Keep in mind, bitlbee remembers which method you use (/msg vs /query) on a per-contact basis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ; however I can't test that right now because I'm migrating my server and bitlbee is far on the list of stuff to re-install. But I'll try to keep that in mind when/if the time comes :)